# Scraping New York Times Word of the Day

Tags: python, scrapy

I've just recently started getting into Scrapy and I've picked New York Times Word of the Day as a first test. https://www.nytimes.com/column/learning-word-of-the-day

I've noticed they have an API but for my exact case it has nothing I could use (I think). I'm basically looking to go through each word of the day on that page and retrieve the word, the meaning and an example paragraph.

This short piece of code should be going through every url and retrieving at least the word but I'm getting a hand full of errors and I have no clue why!
I've been using SelectorGadget to get the CSS codes I need and so far this is my code:

```
import scrapy

class NewYorkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "times"
    start_urls = [ "https://www.nytimes.com/column/learning-word-of-the-day" ]

    # entry point for the spider
    def parse(self,response):
        for href in response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "headline", " " ))]'):
            url = href.extract()
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        word = response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "story-subheading", " " ))]//strong').extract()[0]
```

Thank you, plenty!

Updated Errors (not exactly errors now, just not crawling the supposed info):

```
2017-01-18 01:13:48 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.nytimes.com/column/%3Ch2%20class=%22headline%22%20itemprop=%22headline%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Word%20+%20Quiz:%20spawn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/h2%3E> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2017-01-18 01:13:48 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.nytimes.com/column/%3Ch2%20class=%22headline%22%20itemprop=%22headline%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Word%20+%20Quiz:%20spawn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/h2%3E> (referer: https://www.nytimes.com/column/learning-word-of-the-day)
2017-01-18 01:13:48 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.nytimes.com/column/%3Ch2%20class=%22headline%22%20itemprop=%22headline%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Word%20+%20Quiz:%20introvert%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/h2%3E> (referer: https://www.nytimes.com/column/learning-word-of-the-day)
2017-01-18 01:13:48 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.nytimes.com/column/%3Ch2%20class=%22headline%22%20itemprop=%22headline%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Word%20+%20Quiz:%20funereal%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/h2%3E> (referer: https://www.nytimes.com/column/learning-word-of-the-day)
```

Comment: It would help to know what the actual errors are.

Comment: I've done just that. Sorry for not adding them before. It was such a large output I figured it'd be a huge mess.

Comment: How do you get the scraper to start crawling?

Comment: @GantTheWanderer scrapy runspider scraper.py -o urls.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using xpath expressions in `.css` method, which is meant for css selector expressions.
Simply replace `.css` with `.xpath`:

```
response.css('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "headline", " " ))]')
# to
response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "headline", " " ))]')
```

Regarding your second error - the url that is extracted is not an absolute url, e.g. `/some/sub/page.html`. To convert it to an absolute url you can use `response.urljoin()` function:

```
 for href in response.xpath('...'):
    url = href.extract()
    full_url = response.urljoin(url)
    yield Request(full_url)
```

Regarding your error number three - your xpaths are faulty here. Looks like you used some xpath generator and those things rarely generate anything worthwhile. What you are looking for here is simply an `<a>` node with `story-link` class:

```
urls = response.xpath('//a[@class="story-link"]/@href').extract()
for url in urls:
    yield Request(response.urljoin(full_url))
```

And for your word xpath you can simply use text under  node which is under :

```
word = response.xpath("//h4/strong/text()").extract_first()
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I've done just that and I'm still getting plenty of errors. Editing with new list of errors in a second.

Comment: @LuísCarvalho see my edit regarding the second error you're experiencing.

Comment: thank you, much better now! and I forgot about that, made sense, thank you! updating with list of 'errors'. it's crawling the pages now, just not delivering what I'm looking for!

Comment: updated with the errors. it should be going into each url in that page and retrieving (for example, for the first link - spawn) - 'spawn \ˈspȯn, ˈspän\ noun and verb' , the very first line.

Comment: @LuísCarvalho alright :D. See my edit for how to resolve the third issue you have.

Comment: thank you brother, you're the real deal! indeed, I used an xpath generator! :(

Comment: @LuísCarvalho no problem, xpaths and css selectors are surpsingly easy, so if you are looking to expand on your web-crawling skills, you can't go wrong with learning at least one of those!

Answer (score 1):

This code should work. For getting the other informations you want from the website of each word, you just have to use the appropriate selector with a XPath or CSS expression.

For more info about Selectors I recommend [this](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) site and of course [Google](https://www.google.com/).

```
import scrapy

class NewYorkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "times"
    start_urls = ["https://www.nytimes.com/column/learning-word-of-the-day"]

    # entry point for the spider
    def parse(self,response):
        for href in response.css('a[class="story-link"]::attr(href)'):
            yield scrapy.Request(href.extract(), callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        heading = response.css('h4[class="story-subheading story-content"] strong::text').extract_first()
```